# How do i change IPv4 to Domain Name in intranet application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

How do i change IPv4 (192.168.1.58)  to Domain Name(Abc.com)  in intranet application(IIS 7.5)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a host header.

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Add-host-header-to-a-Web-Site-in-IIS-7-IIS-75.aspx